# retrieving duplicates in table and displaying them

Tags: mysql

I have got the following table where if more than 1 row contain the same  'user_badge_name' and the 'user_email', the are considered duplicates.

```
user_id | user_name | user_badge_name | user_email
--------------------------------------------------
234     | Kylie     | ky001           | kylie@test.com
235     | Francois  | FR007           | france@test.com 
236     | Maria     | MA300           | Marie@test.com
237     | Francine  | FR007           | france@test.com
```

I need to display the user_ids and username of those rows where 'user_badge_name' and 'user_email' are replicated.

I tried the following sql but it is not returning all user_ids, only the first id

```
SELECT user_id, username , COUNT(user_badge_name) AS user_badge_name_Count FROM user GROUP BY user_badge_name HAVING user_badge_name_Count > 1
```

Any suggestion is most appreciated

Comment: If the goal is to prevent duplicate entries, why does the table structure allow them?  If you declare `user_email` and `user_badge_name` as UNIQUE, then you'll never have problems with duplicates in those columns.

Comment: I am using an existing table which already contain duplicates. I just needed to display those duplicates

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select a.user_id, a.user_name
from user as a
inner join
(SELECT user_badge_name, user_email
FROM user
GROUP BY user_badge_name, user_email
HAVING count(*)>1
) as dups
on a.user_badge_name=dups.user_badge_name and a.user_email=dups.user_email
order by a.user_badge_name, a.user_email
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to see all of the user ids in the same row, then you can used a `GROUP_CONCAT`:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(user_id) AS user_ids, GROUP_CONCAT(username) AS usernames, COUNT(user_badge_name) AS user_badge_name_Count FROM user GROUP BY user_badge_name HAVING user_badge_name_Count > 1
```

That will give you something like this:

```
user_ids | usernames         | user_badge_name_Count
-----------------------------------------------
235,237  | Francois,Francine | 2
```

Comment: Thanks for the 'GROUP_CONCAT' suggestion